# How does a Python external library not cause interpreter problems in backwards compatibility with Python2 if it supports Python3 exclusive features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, backwards-compatibility

A few questions about external libraries and how an older Python interpreter handles external libraries that utilize features the older interpreter does not have, and packaging a library that is potentially backward compatible.

I first came across this with the matmul operator and numpy - the matmul (@) operator is a 3.5 feature, when I created this trivial example

```
import numpy as np 

array1 = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
array2 = np.array([3, 4])
array3 = array1 @ array2
```

it throws an invalid syntax error if I run it through python2.7.16 and is fine with Python3.7. Why is the trace not in numpy itself if somewhere it has to have the __matmul__ dunder that didn’t exist in earlier Python? Similarly is the question of type hinting: when I update that little chunk of code with type hints it causes syntax errors everywhere for 2.7 - if someone makes their nice package for 3.x with helpful type hinting inside, a 3.5 feature, someone pip installs it from an egg or wheel, then runs it through python2, how does the interpreter handle that? Same for f-strings, a 3.5/3.6 addition. I ask because I have a package I’d like to distribute as a wheel, ideally it would work for 2.7, but I have type hinting and f strings all over the place.

I think the summary of my questions would be: how can you guarantee your package with all its nice Python3 features is backwards compatible to older Pythons, if you can? How does using an external library or something you’ve installed from a wheel/egg differ from importing? (esp. for an egg, which to my understanding still offers the original source code whereas the wheel has some kind of compilation/“building” going on (not sure what “building” means in the context of Python, my understanding was you feed your source to the interpreter and it generates byte code at run time, the interpreter never “builds”(compiles) an object file or executable like a compiled language))

Comment: At this point, the people requiring Python 2.7 support aren't writing new code: they are maintaining existing code that probably isn't gaining new features. Your target audience will almost certainly be fine with abandoning Python 2 support.

Comment: There was never meant to be a perpetual divide between Python 2 and Python 3; the number of breaking changes made the transition more difficult than anticipated, leading to Python 2's shuttering taking much longer than expected.

Answer (score 1):

In general, either it's a fluke, or they avoided actually *using* any Python 3 features, even if they provided support for such features.

> Why is the trace not in numpy itself if somewhere it has to have the `__matmul__` dunder that didn’t exist in earlier Python?

Just naming a method `__matmul__` isn't a syntax error on Python 2. Trying to use the `@` operator is a syntax error. (NumPy doesn't support Python 2 any more, though, so either you're on an old NumPy or the lack of errors on import is a total fluke.)

> Similarly is the question of type hinting: when I update that little chunk of code with type hints it causes syntax errors everywhere for 2.7 - if someone makes their nice package for 3.x with helpful type hinting inside, a 3.5 feature, someone pip installs it from an egg or wheel, then runs it through python2, how does the interpreter handle that?

There's a "type comment" syntax that works on Python 2, or they can distribute separate type stub files instead of using inline annotations. If they use annotation syntax in their `.py` files directly, that *will* cause a syntax error, though.

> Same for f-strings, a 3.5/3.6 addition.

Syntax error.

> I ask because I have a package I’d like to distribute as a wheel, ideally it would work for 2.7, but I have type hinting and f strings all over the place.

You have unrealistic compatibility expectations. You'll have to use type comments and `str.format`.

> how can you guarantee your package with all its nice Python3 features is backwards compatible to older Pythons, if you can?

By not using Python 3 features.